# Changing Textbox and other UI components in Qt/Webkit?

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I am making my own browser with Qt/Webkit for touch screen devices. I want to have My own editbox in browser ( so that when user click on it, I can open virtual keyboard), Touch friendly listbox and other controls.

So In QWebView I want to have MyOwnTextEdit instread of QTextEdit and same for all other UI controls.

Please tell me How can I do it?

I am using Qt embedded linux 4.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can see how this kind of things realized in more easy widgets here: [link text](http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/). It's the first way. The second way is to create you textbox with SIGNALs/SLOTs and also code widgets GUI with Qt styles. Good luck!

Comment: I can't get you. Please elaborate more on how can I have my own textedit in web browser instead of having QTextEdit in browser?

Comment: @Wallah: wwWidgets is a set of widgets, which were bases on standard Qt widgets. You need to download and unzip code to start search methods to create your own widgets (textbox and etc.). At least for me, it's was like I sad: for example, I was need a special qlineedit widget, with appended qtoolbuttons inside the last one for open directory, which was set in qlineedit. I made new class *class CButtonLineEdit : public QLineEdit* and added some functions for additional functional with *setStyleSheet*...